# How to hold my location after the web page is refreshed

Tags: php

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
     echo " <select data-live-search='true' data-live-search-style='startsWith' class='selectpicker' id='locName'>";
     $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT LocationName From arealistmain');
     $stmt->execute();
     {
         echo  "<option>Select Location</option>";
     }

     $stmt->execute();
     while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
         echo  "<option>" .$row['LocationName'] . "</option>";
     }

    echo "</select>";                           
?>
```

I need to hold the location after the web page is refreshed.

Comment: Do you mean after submitting your form or just simple refresh?

Comment: You can use the session to store user's selected location temporarily. When page refreshed, check session first if it has location stored then show it selected in the drop-down.

Comment: @ d.coder i have used session but once i refresh my page its showing again to select location.my session code for the same  {
       echo " <option>" .$_SESSION['Locationame'] . "</option>";
             }

Answer (score 0):

PHP is stateless so you can't send variables with POST or GET(with cURL you can though).
Either use sessions or cookies

```
//On page 1
$_SESSION['location'] = $location;

//On page 2
$location= $_SESSION['location'];
```

And on page 2 when you do your loop have a check for that value

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
    $selected = '';
    if($row['LocationName'] == $location){
        $selected = 'selected';
    }
    echo  "<option $selected>$row[LocationName]</option>";
}
```

And after you have done it you might wanna unset the $_SESSION variable :

```
unset($_SESSION['location'])
```

Comment: i need to hold my location data in my index page when it is refreshed.i have used session to hold the data.but after that also am getting same result ie to select location

Comment: Care to elaborate? I can't understand your problem.